# Cannot configure X509 Certificate Authenticator with deployment.toml

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

I have WSO2 IS 5.10.0. It uses deployment.toml. When configuring x509 authentication I need to update the file application-authentication.xml with my x509 related values. However, my updates in this file get overwritten when restarting WSO2 IS. I suspect it has to do with deployment.toml. What do I need to do to get x509 working on this version of WSO2 IS?

Comment: What is the configuration you need to add to application-authentication.xml

Comment: Hi I certainly have to add my hostname / port . Probably also username and  setclaimUri and EnforceSerfRegistratin . All in <AuthenticatorConfig name="x509CertificateAuthenticator" enabled="true">
        <Parameter name="AuthenticationEndpoint">https://localhost:8443/x509-certificate-servlet</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="username">CN</Parameter>
</AuthenticatorConfig>

Answer (score 0):

The xml file gets overridden by the default configurations unless you have defined the values in the deployment.toml file. Hence, you can add following configurations (with your values) into the deployment.toml and restart the server to get them applied.

```
[authentication.authenticator.x509_certificate.parameters]
AuthenticationEndpoint ="https://localhost:8443/x509-certificate-servlet"
username = "CN"
setClaimURI = "http://wso2.org/claims/identity/userCertificate"
EnforceSelfRegistration = true
```

Reference: https://github.com/wso2/docs-is/issues/986

EDIT: Add Tomcat connector configs

Adding an extra tomcat connector with `deployment.toml` seems to be not facilitated yet. Hence, we can follow the steps below.

Add following new connector to the template file `repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml.j2` in the correct place.

```
{% for trasport in custom_trasport %}
  <Connector
  {% for name,value in trasport.properties.items() %}
            {{name}}="{{value}}"
  {% endfor %}
  >
  </Connector>
{% endfor %}
```

Then add all the connector properties to the `depoyment.toml` as follows.

```
[custom_trasport.x509.properties]
protocol="HTTP/1.1"
port="8443"
maxThreads="200"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="/path/to/keystore.jks"
keystorePass="keystorepwd"
truststoreFile="/path/to/truststore.jks"
truststorePass="truststorespassword"
bindOnInit = "false"
clientAuth="want"
sslProtocol="TLS"
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift answer. I will try that out and come back. However, I have the same issues with Catalina-server.xml file, it also gets overwritten by the default. In this file I have to add according to the documentation (with my values), and first in the order:

<Connector
        protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        port="8443" maxThreads="200"
        scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       etc....
        clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLS"/>

Is there also here something I can add to the deployment.toml file? If not, what is the solution then?

Comment: @PeterDev20 I have updated the answer with tomcat connector config as well. Please mark this as accepted if it solves your issue.

Comment: Hi again. The both configuration changes has worked, the resulting xml files are now as required. But now the whole server starts on port 8443 instead of 9443, https://wso2server.dev1.test.epo.org:8443/carbon/. As a result the ports used in the resident idp settings are a mix of 8334 and 9334 and many things, like the user portal, does not work anymore. WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} - Provided Callback URL does not match with the provided one. I only want to use 8334 for x509 and the rest to remain on 9443 as before. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Ah, just move the new connector in the j2 template after the existing two connectors

Comment: One step closer. I have now all the parameters in the xml files. I'm prompted to select a certificate in the browser but when selecting one I now get an error. Authentication failed exception! org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException: Unable to find X509 Certificate in browser at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.x509Certificate.X509CertificateAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(X509CertificateAuthenticator.java:204). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> One step closer. I have now all the parameters in the xml files. I'm
> prompted to select a certificate in the browser but when selecting one
> I now get an error. Authentication failed exception!
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException:
> Unable to find X509 Certificate in browser at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.x509Certificate.X509CertificateAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(X509CertificateAuthenticator.java:204).
> Any ideas?

There are two possibilities,

1. You need to import the generated pkcs12 file to the browser.
   Follow this doc to do the import https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+X509Certificate+Authenticator#ConfiguringX509CertificateAuthenticator-Importcertificate
2. If you have already done this step and still getting this error, regenerate the certificate the re-add the cert to the browser. It happened to me because I used a corrupted data file to generate the x509 certificate.