# WSO2 Identity Server X509 Authentication Behind Proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.
I need to add support for X509 Authentication and I was reading the documentation about the X509 Certificate Authentication [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/x509certificate-authenticator/#configuring-x509certificate-authenticator)
In order to add the configuration I had to modify the `catalina-server.xml.j2` file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61629890/cannot-configure-x509-certificate-authenticator-with-deployment-toml)

So done it works but I have a very huge ports commingling.... anyway let's assume it works.

Now I have this issue: I need to deploy WSO2 Identity Server in a K8S cluster. So, basically, I have a nginx ingress controller that will manage all the traffic to the backend.

What I did locally is to put a simple nginx reverse proxy and configure WSO2 Identity Server in order to use this proxy. So in my `deployment.toml` I did the following

```
[custom_trasport.x509.properties]
protocols="HTTP/1.1"
port="8443"
maxThreads="200"
scheme="https"
secure=true
SSLEnabled=true
keystoreFile="mykeystore.jks"
keystorePass="pwd"
truststoreFile="myclient_trust.jks"
truststorePass="myclient_trust_pwd"
bindOnInit=false
clientAuth="want"
sslProtocol = "TLS"
proxyPort="443"


[authentication.authenticator.x509_certificate.parameters]
name ="x509CertificateAuthenticator"
enable=true
AuthenticationEndpoint="https://$ref{server.hostname}:8443/x509-certificate-servlet"
username= "CN"
SearchAllUserStores="false"
EnforceSelfRegistration = "false"
SearchAndValidateUserLocalStores = "false"


[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort="443"
```

In this way when I want to sign-in by using the X509 Certificate Authentication it will ask for my certificate but then, when I choose the certificate, it shows an error because it can't find the certificate in the browser request

Moreover I don't think I should leave `AuthenticationEndpoint="https://$ref{server.hostname}:8443/x509-certificate-servlet"` because this means that the submit will be done to the 8443 port that is never exposed on internet.

Did anyone solve this issue? Basically the question is: how can I configure the X509 Certificate Authentication behind a proxy (e.g. nginx)?

Any tip is very precious.

Thank you

Angelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the issue I'm facing.

Basically when I have a reverse_proxy (e.g. nginx), the certicate doesn't arrive to the tomcat in the request attribute.

What I did is configure the reverse_proxy to put the certificate as HTTP header without verifying it; I'll verify on the server side.

So now my nginx configuration is:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name wso2_iam;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate certificate_full_path.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key full_path_to_kwy_no_pwd.key;
        ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;

       
        location /x509-certificate-servlet/ {
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                   proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
                   proxy_read_timeout 5m;
                   proxy_send_timeout 5m;
                   proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443/x509-certificate-servlet;

                   proxy_http_version 1.1;
                   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
        location / {
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                   proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
                   proxy_read_timeout 5m;
                   proxy_send_timeout 5m;
                   proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9443/;

                   proxy_http_version 1.1;
                   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            }
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/wso2-error.log;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/wso2-access.log;
}
```

The `ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;` tells nginx to retrieve the certificate but to not validate it.

The `proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;` instruction tells nginx to put the certificate PEM based in the request header called `X-SSL-CERT`

Then I modified the `org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.x509Certificate.X509CertificateAuthenticator` in order to search for the certificate between request headers when it's not found in the http request attribute.

It seems to be working.

Thank you to all

Angelo